# Push Notification in iPhone6 (iOS 8) not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, ios8.1, iphone-6

The following are the code that I have written in my appDelegate related to Apple Push Notification. For me, it is a weird issue that I am not receiving the push notification in the `IPHONE6 IOS8` but receiving push in other devices and other versions. If I am lacking something, do I need to do something else for `IPHONE6 IOS8`. Please suggest help me resolve the issue.

```
- (void)callPushNotificationDelegate {
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
#endif
  } else {
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
  }
}
```

## pragma mark - Remote Notification Delegate

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
  [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
#endif

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
  NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error {
  NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```